# Using find elements by class name to get attribute value in Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to grab video IDs from the attribute "data-rbd-drag-handle-draggable-id" from a list of videos using class name "favorites-video favorites-table-spacing" so I can append them to a list containing all the video IDs. Here is an example of the HTML I am using.

```
<div class="favorites-video favorites-table-spacing" data-rbd-draggable-context-id="2" data-rbd-draggable-id="6568ff097b469e24dce6eae8key0" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-describedby="rbd-hidden-text-2-hidden-text-10" data-rbd-drag-handle-draggable-id="6568ff097b469e24dce6eae8key0" data-rbd-drag-handle-context-id="2" draggable="false">


<div class="favorites-video favorites-table-spacing" data-rbd-draggable-context-id="2" data-rbd-draggable-id="6568ff097b469e24dce6eae8key0" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-describedby="rbd-hidden-text-2-hidden-text-10" data-rbd-drag-handle-draggable-id="6568ff097b469e24dce6eae8key0" data-rbd-drag-handle-context-id="2" draggable="false">


<div class="favorites-video favorites-table-spacing" data-rbd-draggable-context-id="2" data-rbd-draggable-id="6552711226e176c233b46379key2" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-describedby="rbd-hidden-text-2-hidden-text-10" data-rbd-drag-handle-draggable-id="6552711226e176c233b46379key2" data-rbd-drag-handle-context-id="2" draggable="false">
```

I made sure using the inspect element that the class name is unique.

I tried using By.CLASS_NAME with the below code which didn't return anything, only [] for id_videolist. How come selenium isn't able to grab the element?

```
id_videolist = []

favvideos = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'favorites-video favorites-table-spacing') 
for video in favvideos:     
    vidId = video.get_attribute('data-rbd-drag-handle-draggable-id') 
    vidId = vidId[:-4]
    id_videolist.append(vidId)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) expression:

```
'//*[@data-rbd-drag-handle-draggable-id]/@data-rbd-drag-handle-draggable-id'
```

:

```
favvideos = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@data-rbd-drag-handle-draggable-id]/@data-rbd-drag-handle-draggable-id')
```

Answer (score 1):

`By.CLASS_NAME` only works for a single class segment. Eg. `"favorites-video"` or `"favorites-table-spacing"`, but not both together.

Also expressed as a `By.CSS_SELECTOR` -> `"div.favorites-video"` or `"div.favorites-table-spacing"`.

For using them together, that would be `'div[class="favorites-video favorites-table-spacing"]'` as a `By.CSS_SELECTOR`.

Your updated line could be:

```py
favvideos = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "favorites-video")
```

Or you can try:

```py
favvideos = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.favorites-video")
```

Comment: Yikes... please don't use `div[class="favorites-video favorites-table-spacing"]` as a CSS selector. It can be better written as `div.favorites-video.favorites-table-spacing`.

Comment: Definitely! Mainly just explaining valid vs invalid selectors.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, CLASS_NAME only accepts a single CSS class name, e.g. 'favorites-video' or 'favorites-table-spacing'. If either is unique enough on the page, you can use them but if you need both you should use a CSS selector, `div.favorites-video.favorites-table-spacing`.

Your updated code would be

```
id_videolist = []

favvideos = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.favorites-video.favorites-table-spacing') 
for video in favvideos:     
    vidId = video.get_attribute('data-rbd-drag-handle-draggable-id') 
    vidId = vidId[:-4]
    id_videolist.append(vidId)
```